# number of instances the cloud foundry app is running

Tags: cloud-foundry

my app needs to get the number of instances in which its running, (in runtime my app uses this info in my program logic).
(VCAP_APPLICATION env variables cannot provide this info. )
Calling API directly and using "instances" attribute is an option, but I dont know how to call apps API directly in my app. Please let me know how to call it.
Below is the link I got for app API:
http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/218/apps/retrieve_a_particular_app.html

Comment: Can you explain how you're using this information? It's not common to use this in your applications. Along with finding out the number of instances, you will have to monitor the state in case of changes.

Comment: I'm doing a performance testing of my Spring boot app running in cf. Now I need to know the no of instances the app is running. I'm using it just to display that the app is running on this much instances. I posted this question in cf-dev list forum and got a reply saying:
- have the app call the API directly and see what the "instances" attribute is set to. http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/218/apps/retrieve_a_particular_app.html

but I don't know how to call my app API. If there is any other way for my app to know the #NoOfInstances, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you shell out and use the cf command line tool in your performance test app? Try cf app --help to show you the format. It will return the number of instances for a particular app. I'm sure it's using the above mentioned api.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use the API, you first need to authenticate. In order to authenticate, you need to retrieve the authorization endpoint.

To retrieve the authorization endpoint, issue the following curl request (I am using pivotal web services in this example, but you would replace https://api.run.pivotal.io with the cloud foundry api endpoint you are using.

```
curl -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' \
-H 'accept: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/info
```

You'll get back something that looks like this:

```
{
"name": "vcap",
"build": "2222",
"support": "http://support.cloudfoundry.com",
"version": 2,
"description": "Cloud Foundry sponsored by Pivotal",
"authorization_endpoint": "https://login.run.pivotal.io",
"token_endpoint": "https://uaa.run.pivotal.io",
"min_cli_version": null,
"min_recommended_cli_version": null,
"api_version": "2.36.0",
"app_ssh_endpoint": "ssh.run.pivotal.io:2222",
"app_ssh_host_key_fingerprint": "e7:13:4e:32:ee:39:62:df:54:41:d7:f7:8b:b2:a7:6b",
"logging_endpoint": "wss://loggregator.run.pivotal.io:443",
"doppler_logging_endpoint": "wss://doppler.run.pivotal.io:443"
}
```

Grab the **authorization_endpoint** value, in this case it is:

https://login.run.pivotal.io

You now need to grab an authentication token. Issue the following curl command replacing the **[my user name]** and **[my password]** and **[my authorization endpoint]** with your values. Please note that you should url encode your password.

```
curl -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' \
-H 'accept: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
-H 'authorization: Basic Y2Y6' \
-d "username=[my user name]&password=[my password]&grant_type=password" \
[my authorization endpoint]/oauth/token
```

You will get a response that looks like this:

```
{
"access_token": "very_long_token.very_long_token.very_long_token",
"token_type": "bearer",
"refresh_token": "very_long_token.very_long_token.very_long_token",
"expires_in": 599,
"scope": "cloud_controller.read password.write cloud_controller.write openid",
"jti": "shorter_value"
}
```

You are interested in the access_token value (access_token, refresh_token, and jti have been changed from the actual values in this example)

Now we are finally at the point where we can use the api to get the information about our app. You could use the link you provided above, but to use that api endpoint, you need the guid of your app. Instead I would recommend using the **List all Apps** endpoint and use a query filter on it to get your app information. Here is the curl command (replace **[my authorization token]** with your auth token from the previous step, replace **[my api endpoint]** with the api endpoint you use for cloud foundry, replace **[my app name]** with the name of your app:

```
curl -H "authorization: bearer [my authorization token]" \
[my api endpoint]/v2/apps?q=name:[my app name] -X GET
```

You'll receive a message that looks like this:

```
{
"total_results": 1,
"total_pages": 1,
"prev_url": null,
"next_url": null,
"resources": [
{
  "metadata": {
    "guid": "blah-blah",
    "url": "/v2/apps/blah-blah",
    "created_at": "time_stamp",
    "updated_at": null
  },
  "entity": {
    "name": "my-app",
    "production": false,
    "space_guid": "blah-blah",
    "stack_guid": "blah-blah",
    "buildpack": null,
    "detected_buildpack": null,
    "environment_json": {

    },
    "memory": 1024,
    "instances": 3,
    "disk_quota": 1024,
    "state": "STOPPED",
    "version": "blah-blah",
    "command": null,
    "console": false,
    "debug": null,
    "staging_task_id": null,
    "package_state": "STAGED",
    "health_check_type": "port",
    "health_check_timeout": null,
    "staging_failed_reason": null,
    "staging_failed_description": null,
    "diego": false,
    "docker_image": null,
    "package_updated_at": "time stamp",
    "detected_start_command": "",
    "enable_ssh": true,
    "docker_credentials_json": {
      "redacted_message": "[PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]"
    },
    "space_url": "/v2/spaces/blah-blah",
    "stack_url": "/v2/stacks/blah-blah",
    "events_url": "/v2/apps/blah-blah/events",
    "service_bindings_url": "/v2/apps/blah-blah/service_bindings",
    "routes_url": "/v2/apps/blah-blah/routes"
  }
}
]
}
```

You can grab the instances from the message. If you want to use the api in your original link, you can grab the metadata.guid for use in that call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks it worked in command line. Now my app while running in cf, needs to get the number of instances and it is using this info in the program logic. what shall I do to my code to get the number of instances my app is running.

Comment: Hmmm, so you are running your performance test as an app in cf and hitting other apps running in cf? Maybe if you share more details, i can help. 
I used curl to show the basic commands used to go through the flow. Depending on your programming language, you would use an oauth library and json parsing to get at the information you desire.
Actually, I would stand up a separate micro service to encapsulate this behavior and have your performance testing app call the microservice to get the info it needs.

Comment: I dont have a separate app like 'performance test' app. I have a single app, which needs to get the number of instances in which its running in cf. Usually this #numberofInstances will be given by us in manifest.yml. 
In command line I can get this info as you said above, but how does my my app get this info in runtime. 
My springboot web app is accessed thru browser to display some data, along with this information I need #numberofInstances to be displayed as well. To display it, my program should first get this during runtime.

Comment: With Cloud Foundry, each app runs in its own isolated container. It is intended to be unaware of other instances of itself running in other containers. Cloud Foundry ensures that the desired amount of instances are running. If you are building a dashboard that shows all of your apps running and their instances, that would be a separate app and would use oauth and json parsing to pull the information from the URIs above.

Comment: i'm not building any dashboard in my project, so what shall do here to get this done.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that you are thinking about this incorrectly. Your app shouldn't care about how many instances of it are deployed. I would build a separate app that monitors the number of instances of various applications. If you really want to use the api from within your app, look at Spring Rest Template or Oauth2 Rest Template to bring the curl flow above into your Spring Boot app.

Comment: Here is a blog post that should help you connect the dots between the flow I posted above and integration into your app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868377/number-of-instances-the-cloud-foundry-app-is-running

Comment: All of this would be made much easier by using the Cloud Foundry Java Client to interact with CF instead of coding all this yourself. The Java Client handles all the OAuth interactions and implements many CF API calls. You can view the Maven plugin code for examples: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/blob/master/cloudfoundry-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/maven/App.java#L38-L39.

Comment: FYI - this API gives you DESIRED state of the app... not the ACTUAL state. For example, a crashing 2, instance app will show STARTED and 2 instances when when actually, 0 instances are actually running. You'll want to specifically check the instances API to verify they match desired. See https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/6.6.0/apps/get_the_instance_information_for_a_started_app.html

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something similar but using cf cli, to get the instance count of my app in a shell script. I came up with this and it works.

```
cf app my_app_name|grep instances|cut -d'/' -f2
```

I understand this post might not be related, but i would be happy if it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is late now to reply - an alternate solution would be to have a service discovery component like Eureka and let your application register to it. From the discovery client, you can get the number of instances for this application.

Be aware though, the state of instances would be eventually consistent on Eureka. We are using this pattern for a cluster broadcast use case.

Answer (score 0):

create a container to container link with the name myapp.apps.internal. Then count the IP's returned by a DNS lookup of myapp.apps.internal.