# my app needs to get the number of instances in which its running (in cloud foundry)

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have a spring boot app pushed into cf. Now my app while running needs to get the number of instances in which my app is running. It is using this info in the program logic. what shall I do to my code to get this info. 
(Will redeploy the app after needed changes made to my project)

Comment: i didn't try anything yet to get the #NoofInstances. I just have my Spring boot web application running in cf. Now in runtime my app somehow should get #NoofInstances info, I gonna make use of this #NoofInstances in my program logic. Don't know how to get this.

Comment: The flow is in my answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868377/number-of-instances-the-cloud-foundry-app-is-running . You need to use Spring's RestTemplate, or Spring's Oauth2RestTemplate to call these apis and get at the information you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/products/how-to-integrate-an-application-with-cloud-foundry-using-oauth2

It should get you going along with the answer I posted to your other question: 
[number of instances the cloud foundry app is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868377/number-of-instances-the-cloud-foundry-app-is-running)